# Is there a way to trace who invoked onNext() on a Subject, in RxJava(2)?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am developing an Android app (It doesn't matter though) using RxJava2, and in some singleton there are some `PublishProcessor`s.

And there are a lot of `.onNext()` calls on these `PublishProcessor`s all over the project.

Now in order to debug, I need to know, on every `.onNext()` called, which line in my project invoked this `.onNext()`.

Is there a way in RxJava(2) that I can achieve this?

Comment: Instead of exposing the processor instance, expose some object where you can intercept the call to `onNext` before it goes into the processor's onNext.

Comment: Then I would have to modify all those calls, which I can just add logs to all those calls as well... I was seeking an easier way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, thanks to @PhanVanLinh, I found a solution that worked for me.

(Actually it has pretty much nothing to do with RxJava...)

You just need to print the stacktrace using `Thread.currentThread.stackTrace` and print it to your own string inside `doOnNext()`, but remember to do it **before** `.observeOn()` so that the thread won't switch, it must stay at the original thread that called `.onNext()`, otherwise you won't get meaningful information.

Then you will know which line that called `.onNext()`.

Comment: This help use trace the thread which invoked `onNext` not able to trace which line in code invoked right?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh you can get line number from the StackTrace object

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `Frames` tab in `Debug` menu.
For example, in this case, `MainActivity` line 18 trigger `onNext`

[image]

Comment: Hm this would work if it doesn't involve thread change (which is probably OK for my case). But I have really a lot of calls on them, do you have any idea how to log it without using debugger?

Comment: Sorry, for log, currently I don't know any solution. I just search and see that https://www.google.com/search?q=rxjava+logging&rlz=1C1CHBD_enMY807MY807&oq=rxjava+logging&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.4715j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8. Maybe you can try it. If you  found a solution, please post the answer. It may help lot of people